# How to add PreShutdown event to ATL service?

Tags: c++, winapi, service, atl

I've inherited the C++ code for an old ATL based service which contains the basic structures from the old ATL wizards (_tWinMain(), Run(), RunMessageLoop() etc).

In particular, this code already handles "Shutdown" and "Stop" events - and I've been asked to add an additional closedown item into the "PreShutdown" event.

I've added the SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN option..

```
m_status.dwControlsAccepted |= SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN
```

..but I can't see how to catch the resulting event - SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN - as ATL appears to provide for "OnShutdown" and "OnClose" methods but doesn't contain an entry for "OnPreShutdown" that I can see.

Can anyone point me at something which will allow me to add an OnPreShutdown to my existing code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that ATL uses `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler` instead of `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`; only the second of these actually registers for the `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN` message. Further, ATL does not contain an inheritable template for OnPreShutdown().

The solution is therefore in four parts:

(1) Update the list of accepted control messages to include the `SERVICE_ACCEPTED_PRESHUTDOWN` message. You can remove the `SERVICE_ACCEPTED_SHUTDOWN` as Windows deems the service to be shut down once you have handled the Pre-Shutdown so you will never receive this message. In my case the change was to the list of controls set in the overridden `PreMessageLoop()` method:

I changed: `m_status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;`

To: `m_status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;`

However you may not have overridden this method - so you should simply change that list at whatever point you are setting this value. *(IInspectable (see other answer) recommends considering the constructor.)*

(2) Override `ServiceMain()`, replacing it entirely by cloning the code and updating it to use `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`. The key change is:

Change: `m_hServiceStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(m_szServiceName, _Handler);`

To: `m_hServiceStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx(m_szServiceName, (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION_EX)_Handler, NULL);`

but you will also need to change references to `pT` and `T` to be `this` in order to remove the templating code (you can also remove the line defining `pT`); for example:

Change: `hr = T::InitializeCom();`

To: `hr = this->InitializeCom();`

Do **not** include a call to the base class (as this would include a call to `RegisterServiceCtrlHandler`).

(3) Override and extend `Handler()`. This requires the addition of new code such as:

```
void CServiceModule::Handler(_In_ DWORD dwOpcpde) throw()
{
    switch (dwOpcode)
    {
        case SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN:
            this->OnPreShutdown();
            break;

        default:
            __super::Handler(dwOpcode);
            break;
    }
}
```

*(Thanks to IInspectable (see other answer) for helping point me in the right direction on this bit.)*

(4) You can now implement an `OnPreShutdown()` method:

```
void CServiceModule::OnPreShutdown() throw()
{
    // custom handling code
    // ...

    // note: service must shutdown in this handler, so finish
    //       by notifying this to SCM.
    SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED);
}
```

Note that Windows expects the service to be stopped during the pre-shutdown if you use it, and once the above is implemented your service will not receive any `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` messages (as it should already be shut down). To allow Windows to carry on shutting other services down you therefore need to add a final `SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_STOPPED)` call at the end of your `OnPreShutdown()` method.

Comment: The bottom line then is: ATL hasn't been updated to include [features](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685058.aspx), that have been around since at least Windows XP/Server 2003. That's a bit saddening. Good job on the analysis and solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing services using ATL is covered at [ATL Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74y2334x.aspx). To handle control requests that a default ATL-generated service wouldn't, you need to extend the default-generated [`Handler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt3s14t0.aspx) implementation.

This is a rough sketch for what you need to do (in addition to registering for the control request, which you already are):

```
void CMyServiceModule::Handler(DWORD dwOpcode) throw() {
    if (SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN == dwOpcode) {
        // Perform custom handling
    }
    else {
        // Pass all other control codes to default implementation
        __super::Handler(dwOpcode);
    }
}
```

As an alternative, you could override the [`OnUnknownRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/caxh4fac.aspx) member in your custom implementation. This member is called for all codes that aren't handled by the default implementation:

```
void CMyServiceModule::OnUnknownRequest(DWORD dwOpcode) {
    if (SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN == dwOpcode) {
        // Perform custom handling
    }
    else {
        // Possibly handle other control codes
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, thanks for answering. Secondly, I already tried to override the Handler in exactly the way you describe above, but never entered the "custom handling" block.  It looks like using the PRESHUTDOWN might also require an override of ServiceMain due to its embedded use of RegisterServiceCtrlHandler instead of RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx (which appears to be required for preshutdown cotrol message). I'll take a closer look at OnUnknownRequest to see if I can get the message there.

Comment: I've just confirmed that I don't get the pre-shutdown control message in the OnUnknownRequest either. (Probably because of ATL using Handler via RegisterServiceCtrlHandler instead of HandlerEx via RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx, but I'm not 100% sure.)

Comment: @Nick: This isn't exactly clear from the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt3s14t0.aspx), but you have to add `m_status.dwControlsAccepted |= SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN;` in your constructor. Setting it at any other time is potentially too late. Since you didn't mention it in your question, where did you update the `m_status` member?

Comment: The previous (working) code is using `m_status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN` in the overridden _PreMessageLoop()_, immediately before signalling `SetServiceStatus(SERVICE_START_PENDING)`. I simply changed this line to `m_status.dwControlsAccepted = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_PRESHUTDOWN`. (Setting this occurs in only this line in the code for this service.)

Comment: @Nick: Try to put it in the constructor to be safe, that it isn't inadvertently being used before having been fully initialized.

Comment: I worked overnight on overriding ServiceMain() in order to use `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`, and once I had that working the overridden `Handler()` began to receive the messages. I thank you for your help (upvoted) and have documented the full solution as an alternative answer.